# How to make a solar eclipse occur in Terraria Mobile edition?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I don't know how to get a solar eclipse to happen. If there is a glitch to do it I would like to know how to do the glitch. How do I make a solar eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

In the PC version of Terraria, the only way to manually start a [solar eclipse](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Solar_Eclipse) is by crafting and using a [solar tablet](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Solar_Tablet). This item is *only* available on PC, so unfortunately for mobile you are not able to intentionally start a solar eclipse. You'll have to wait until one happens naturally. They only start to happen (with a 5% chance each day) after beating at least one mechanical boss.

Answer (score 0):

A page can be found [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Talk:Solar_Eclipse) suggesting different ways to make this happen, and this is not an OFFICIAL GUIDE more of a discussion page which people seem to beleive work for example:

> Slightly increased the chance for an eclipse to happen, but they will now only happen after killing a Mechanical Boss
>   So does that mean that each time there's a solar eclipse, you have to kill another mechanical boss to get the next eclipse? Or just that killing a single mechanical boss enables any number of eclipses? -- KhymChanur (talk) 02:48, 10 October 2013 (UTC)
>   its a boolean, if player has killed a mech boss, then eclipsi will happen. 67.233.98.29 03:07, 10 October 2013 (UTC)

Answer (score -1):

On mobile (I'm on mine) a solar eclipse only happens by chance at night, so you don't have to kill any mechanical bosses...

Comment: How do you make it happen though?

Answer (score -1):

On mobile after night there is a small chance a solar eclipse will **replace** the day if you’ve beaten a mechanical boss I may be wrong it may be all three mechanicl bosses.